# MDX: Invalid procedure call or argument when substracting

Tags: types, mdx, mismatch

I am struggling with the following statement:

```
    WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Diff Geo Volumen Artikelnummer] as 

[D_Artikel].[Geo Max Volumen Artikelnummer].CurrentMember.Member_Value- --remark1
[D_Artikel].[Geo Min Volumen Artikelnummer].CurrentMember.Member_Value



SELECT non empty 
{[Measures].[Menge_Artikel_Stk], [Measures].[Diff Geo Volumen Artikelnummer]} on 0,

NON EMPTY 
crossjoin(
filter([D_Artikel].[Artikelnummer].[Artikelnummer],[Measures].[Diff Geo Volumen Artikelnummer]>0) , -- remark2
[D_Artikel].[Geo Max Volumen Artikelnummer].[Geo Max Volumen Artikelnummer],
[D_Artikel].[Geo Min Volumen Artikelnummer].[Geo Min Volumen Artikelnummer])
on 1 
FROM [Tag_PL_Bestand_Cube_TM] 
WHERE ([D_Datum].[Datum].[Tag].&[2017-06-06T00:00:00])
```

[image: Members of Dimension]

1) remark1: The calculation works when replacing the substraction with an addition. Why? 
2) remark2: The substraction works when not using the filter function...

Unfortunately, I want to filter and substract... Eventually I want to use Excel Pivot  to access the data and create the new measure in Excel.

> The error message says: Executing the query ... Query (3, 1)
>   Typenkonflikt beim Subtract-Operator. Systemfehler:  Invalid procedure
>   call or argument Run complete

*Typenkonflikt = type mismatch

Instead of the Member_Value I have also tried .Value and .MemberValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tells you line 3 is at fault: Query (**3**, 1)

Comments in mdx are ignored using `//` not like sql `--`

This should function better:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Diff Geo Volumen Artikelnummer] as 
  //remark1
  [D_Artikel].[Geo Max Volumen Artikelnummer].CurrentMember.Member_Value- 
  [D_Artikel].[Geo Min Volumen Artikelnummer].CurrentMember.Member_Value
...
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have actually added the remark - comments only here in the text-window. But after trying different things I came up with a solution I don't really understand but which served well enough:

Instead of using the Member_Value function I have replaced it with .Properties("Key0",typed)

Another approach is using DAX instead of MDX I guess. Seems more straightforwards to me for easy calculations.